# How do i model multiple photos (for a Hotel) with schema.org?

Tags: data-modeling, schema.org

I am new to schema.org. Currently i am trying to use it as our internal data model for imports as it offers a good "common ground" for all source systems.

The Hotel schema (https://schema.org/Hotel) offers a "photo" (singular) property, it inherits from Place. It used to have a "photos" (plural) property in the past.

When using schema.org for markup, this would not matter, as i can just mark up multiple elements as "photo".

- However, when using it as a data class, how should i model it?
- Should i just make it an array of Photograph?
- If yes, does schema.org actually assume on ANY property that it may be multiple (amenityFeature, availableLanguage, etc. suspiciously look like that)?
- Does that mean, i have to actually model every property as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research i have to assume schema.org is not meant as a full data model. It is mostly about providing a common vocabulary and a hierarchy of information. Its primary use case seems to be markup, so types definitions are very vague since they have to work on content that is actually meant to be presented to a user. So i will have to specify my own schema and let my decisions and my naming be guided by schema.org.